# Transversality of Flags

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-spaces, grassmannian

I'm struggling to understand the transversality of flags:

The statement "any general pair of distinct flags $\mathbb{F}_{1}$
and $\mathbb{F}_{2}$
can be mapped by a suitable element of GL(n) to a specific pair consisting
of the standard flag $\mathbb{E}$,  with $E_i = \operatorname{Span} \{e_1, \ldots, e_i\}$ and the opposite flag $\mathbb{E}'$  with
$E_i' = \operatorname{Span} \{e_{n−i+1}, \ldots , e_{n}\}$" doesn't seem true to me.

For example if I take the flags

$$\mathbb{F}_{1}=\operatorname{Span}\{e_{1}\}\subsetneq \operatorname{Span}\{e_{1}, e_{2}\}\subsetneq \operatorname{Span}\{e_{1}, e_{2},e_{3}\}$$

and

$$\mathbb{F}_{2}=\operatorname{Span}\{e_{2}\}\subsetneq\operatorname{Span}\{e_{2}, e_{1}\}\subsetneq\operatorname{Span}\{e_{2}, e_{1},e_{3}\},$$

what is the right $g \in GL(n)$ to choose, to make the flags meet transversally?

It seems false to me as $\operatorname{Span} \{e_2\} \subset \operatorname{Span}\{e_1, e_2\}$, $ \ $and this will still be the case under the action of $g \in GL(n)$.

Comment: A formatting tip for the future: when you want format "span" or another such thing that isn't already supported by math mode, you should use \operatorname{Span}: this handles spacing much better than the MathJax/LaTeX code you were using before. I've gone ahead and upgraded your post using this so you can see how it works.

Comment: @KReiser Thanks a lot for the tip! I'll make sure to use it in the future.

Comment: Where does this statement come from? It seems wrong to me.

Comment: @RobArthan http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~simonm/schubertcalculusreview.pdf, page 11

Comment: I can only conjecture that by "general" the authors mean something like "in general position" or alternatively that "distinct`" is intended to be a technical term (that they haven't defined).